# Windows batch password protection?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, passwords

I'm stuck with a batch file for password protection of Windows command prompt. Neither way works properly. If it does not display syntax error, it can't go over even when typing in correct password. Here is the code:

```
@echo off
echo Computer password protected.
echo.

:PSW
set /p "PASS" = "Enter password: "
IF "%PASS%"=="kerberos" (
    echo Welcome.
    echo.
    goto EOF
) ELSE (
    echo Wrong password! Try again.
    echo.
    goto PSW
)

:EOF
```

I kept the password as it is just a test to see if it is working properly and how it actually works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put `"` or spaces in your `set` command.

e.g.

```
C:\Users\marc>set /p "pass" = "prompt: "
prompt: argle

C:\Users\marc>set /P "pass2"= "prompt: "
prompt: bargle

C:\Users\marc>set
[..snip..]
pass" =argle
pass2"=bargle
```

Note how the `"` and space became part of the environment variable.

Do this instead:

```
C:\Users\marc>set /p pass3="prompt: "
                     ^^^^^^^---note: no quotes, no space
prompt: kittens

C:\Users\mbb190>echo %pass3%
kittens
```

Comment: You can also quote the assignment `set /p "pass3=prompt: "`

Answer (score 1):

The `set /p` syntax is wrong. You need to use:

```
set /p PASS="Enter password: "
```

Comment: So the same script does not work under MS-DOS running in virtual machine. Looks like I have to search for another syntax to get a prompted value in a variable.

Comment: as far as I can remember, `set` does not support the `/P` switch in pure MS-DOS unfortunately...

Comment: I already checked that in MS-DOS help. I don't know how to make user-friendly filling of variable by prompt line in MS-DOS. Maybe it was not designed to be that possible by simple batch scripts. A simple program could actualy do the job, but it needs first to be written in QuickBasic or other programming language and then compiled to EXE or COM (COM would be better). Also it should then handle other characters like spaces and special characters for interpunction. Smart then might use DOS install floppy, reboot, exit install and remove the batch line (and possible delete the program).